# Jenkins (Windows Service) with Git over SSH

Tags: jenkins, git, windows

I'm having a hard time configuring Jenkins, running as a Windows Service, to connect to a git server (gitosis) and clone a repository. Jenkins is set to use the standard [Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

Everything is hosted by us: the Jenkins server is on `win.foo.com` and gitosis is running on a linux server (`git.foo.com`).

If I RDP into `win.foo.com` I can clone (`git.exe clone --progress -o origin git@git.foo.com:myproject.git myproject`) from the command line without issue.

Jenkins is running as a service and because it's not running under the same user account I've copied the `.ssh` folder to `%SystemRoot%\System32\config\systemprofile` (as defined in the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable) and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\`, but neither of these seem to be picked up by Jenkins, even after a full restart.

I've tried using both `git.exe` and `git.cmd`; no joy in either case.

Jenkins is failing with the following error message:

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@git.foo.com:myproject.git
ERROR: Cause: Error performing command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd clone --progress -o origin git@git.foo.com:myproject.git C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\myproject\workspace
Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd clone --progress -o origin git@git.foo.com:myproject.git C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\myproject\workspace" returned status code 128: Cloning into C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\myproject\workspace...
Access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm sure I've missed something, but I'm not sure what.

Advice?

Comment: @Mchl: quite true, actually... voted to close (migrate to SF) as well.

Answer (score 4):

I've been reading the following article, which is closely related: [How do I tell Git for Windows where to find my private RSA key?](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key) and it gave a good hint: The HOME-Variable is crucial, but it didn't work out the way I thought.

After a lot of reasearch and trying I found this article:
http://markashleybell.com/portable-git-windows-setting-home-environment-variable.html

In fact it is not enough to set the environment-variable in windows as usual, when running ssh from a service account, but change the configuration so the keys are actually found.

**Short relevant outline:**

Navigate to C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile
and add the following line

```
HOME="/c/Users/YourUserAccount"
```

before

```
# normalize HOME to unix path
HOME="$(cd "$HOME" ; pwd)"
```

This solved it for me, because now Git *always* uses your statically assigned path for home. Just make sure you don't get any security-issues with this approach with other users on this machine.

Comment: **make sure you don't get any security-issues with this approach with other users on this machine** - this should be in bold font in your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The only parameter you need to *really* check is the `%HOME%` environment variable value, when Jenkins tries to clone.
You need to display the 'set' (environments variable) of the Jenkins session and see if `HOME` has been defined, and if it has, to which path.

Reminder:

- Windows, by default, doesn't define `HOME`
- msysgit defaults `HOME` to `%USERPROFILE%`

---

To display the variables, use the [Parametrized build feature](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Build):

> Reference parameter by name in builder. I'm using the "`env`" command to show the variable, followed by an echo statement to demonstrate referencing the value:

[image: command shell in parametrized Jenkins job]

Comment: Any idea how I can view the `%HOME%` env variable through Jenkins?

Comment: @unpluggd: I have edited my answer to address your question.

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't show that `HOME` is set though; as you said, `HOME` isn't set by default. Is it possible to set this?

Comment: @unpluggd: on Windows, HOME isn't set, that means you have to set it either on the User Environment Variable side, or on the System Environment variable side as in http://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/

Comment: Still getting `access denied`! There's no `HOME` var even though Jenkins is now running as a new user.

Comment: @Philip: "There's no HOME var": that needs to be addressed. Did you define HOME as a system environment variable?

Comment: @VonC let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/991/discussion-between-phillip-oldham-and-vonc)